# Decrypt in Snowflake using Unix command

Tags: unix, encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am facing an issue where I have to decrypt a db column in Snowflake.The transformation to decrypt the column is a unix command.How do I achieve this decryption in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a row with normal data and one column that is encrypted, and

1. are not prepared to decrypt the column prior to loading the data into Snowflake
2. you are also not prepared to decrypt the column after returning result rows from Snowflake via a query.

Then point 2 would imply you ether cannot decrypt client side, OR you need the results to do some form of JOIN/Filtering on, that it would make sense to store the data non-encrypted.

When you refer to decrypt as a command line tool, implies to you are ether encrypting the whole file/pipe-stream with does not match your column reference.

But if you have to decrypt in Snowflake you will need to implement a [Javascript UDF](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js.html) to do that. You might find the [Using Binary Data](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/binary-examples.html#custom-decoding-with-javascript-udf) doc's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run unix commands in the Snowflake environment.

If you can't do client side decryption on the way in or out, you have to figure out what the unix command actually does and hopefully you will be able to recreate it using the [Cryptographic/Checksum functions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-string.html).